# Is there a way to optimize my list comprehension for better performance? It is slower than a for loop

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am trying to optimize my code for looping through an ASC raster file. The input to the function is the data array from the ASC file with the shape 1.000 x 1.000 (1mio data points), the ASC file information and a column skipping value. The skip value is not important in this case.

My function with a for loop code performs decent and skips an array cell if the data == nodata_value. Here is the function:

```
def asc_process_single(self, asc_array, asc_info, skip=1):
    # ncols = asc_info['ncols']
    nrows = asc_info['nrows']
    xllcornor = asc_info['xllcornor']
    yllcornor = asc_info['yllcornor']
    cellsize = asc_info['cellsize']
    nodata_value = asc_info['nodata_value']

    raster_size_y = cellsize*nrows
    # raster_size_x = cellsize*ncols

    # Looping over array rows and cols with skipping
    xyz = []
    for row in range(asc_array.shape[0])[::skip]:
        for col in range(asc_array.shape[1])[::skip]:
            val_z = asc_array[row, col]  # Z value of datapoint

            # The no data value is not processed
            if val_z == nodata_value:
                pass
            else:
                # Xcoordinate for current Z value
                val_x = xllcornor + (col * cellsize)

                # Ycoordinate for current Z value
                val_y = yllcornor + raster_size_y - (row * cellsize)

                # x, y, z to LIST
                xyz.append([val_x, val_y, val_z])
    return xyz
```

Timing this for 7 repeats on an ASC file where nodata_value(s) are present is:

```
593 ms ± 34.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I thought i could do this better with a list comprehension:

```
def asc_process_single_listcomprehension(self, asc_array, asc_info, skip=1):
        # ncols = asc_info['ncols']
        nrows = asc_info['nrows']
        xllcornor = asc_info['xllcornor']
        yllcornor = asc_info['yllcornor']
        cellsize = asc_info['cellsize']
        nodata_value = asc_info['nodata_value']

        raster_size_y = cellsize*nrows
        # raster_size_x = cellsize*ncols

        # Looping over array rows and cols with skipping
        rows = range(asc_array.shape[0])[::skip]
        cols = range(asc_array.shape[1])[::skip]
        
        xyz = [[xllcornor + (col * cellsize),
               yllcornor + raster_size_y - (row * cellsize),
               asc_array[row, col]]
               for row in rows for col in cols
               if asc_array[row, col] != nodata_value] 
        
        return xyz
```

However, this performs slower than my for loop and i am wondering why?

```
757 ms ± 58.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Is it because the list comprehension looks up asc_array[row, col] twice? This operation alone cost

```
193 ns ± 11.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

versus just assigning using the z value from an already lookup value in the array in my for loop

```
51.2 ns ± 1.18 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Doing this 1 mio times would add up the time spent doing this for the list comprehension.
Any ideas how to optimize my list comprehension further so it is better performing than my for loop? Any other ideas to improve performance?

EDIT:
Solution:
I tried the 2 proposals given.

1. Reference my Z value in my list comprehension and not do
   the lookup in the array twice which took longer to do.
2. Rewrrite the function to handle the problem with numpy arrays

The list comprehension i rewrote to this:

```
xyz = [[xllcornor + (col * cellsize),
               yllcornor + raster_size_y - (row * cellsize),
               val_z]
               for row in rows for col in cols for val_z in 
[asc_array[row, col]]
               if val_z != nodata_value]
```

and the numpy function became this:

```
def asc_process_numpy_single(self, asc_array, asc_info, skip):
    # ncols = asc_info['ncols']
    nrows = asc_info['nrows']
    xllcornor = asc_info['xllcornor']
    yllcornor = asc_info['yllcornor']
    cellsize = asc_info['cellsize']
    nodata_value = asc_info['nodata_value']

    raster_size_y = cellsize*nrows
    # raster_size_x = cellsize*ncols

    rows = np.arange(0,asc_array.shape[0],skip)[:,np.newaxis]
    cols = np.arange(0,asc_array.shape[1],skip)

    x = np.zeros((len(rows),len(cols))) + xllcornor + (cols * cellsize)
    y = np.zeros((len(rows),len(cols))) + yllcornor + raster_size_y - (rows * 
    cellsize)
    z = asc_array[::skip,::skip]

    xyz = np.asarray([x,y,z]).T.transpose((1,0,2)).reshape( 
    (int(len(rows)*len(cols)), 3) )
    mask = (xyz[:,2] != nodata_value)
    xyz = xyz[mask]
    return xyz
```

I added the mask in the last 2 lines of the numpy function because i dont want the nodata_values.
The performance is as follows in the order; for loop, list comprehension, list comprehension suggestion and numpy function suggestion:

```
609 ms ± 44.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1 loop each)
706 ms ± 22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1 loop each)
604 ms ± 21.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1 loop each)
70.4 ms ± 1.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The list comprehension compares to the for loop when optimized, but the numpy function speeds up the party with a factor of 9.

Thank you so much for your comments and suggestions. I learned a lot today.

Comment: So, the conclusion seems to be that in your case, a list comprehension is not faster. You can have a look at https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops for a few tips that might (or not) help you gain a little time.

Comment: also: for assessing large data arrays you should switch to numpy arrays (instead of lists) and numpy functions (instead of for-loops). this will vastly improve the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assessing your array twice increases the calculation time. Here are my test cases:

```
def funLoop(A):
    xyz = []
    for row in range(A.shape[0]):
        for col in range(A.shape[1]):
            xyz.append([col, row, A[row, col] ])
            
def funListComp1(A):
    xyz = [ [col, row, A[row, col] ] 
           for row in range(A.shape[0]) for col in range(A.shape[1])]

def funListComp2(A):
    xyz = [ [col, A[row, col], A[row, col] ] 
           for row in range(A.shape[0]) for col in range(A.shape[1])]
    
A = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
%timeit funLoop(A)
%timeit funListComp1(A)
%timeit funListComp2(A)
```

```
457 ms ± 70.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
378 ms ± 8.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
779 ms ± 309 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

With respect to large data you should always prefer using numpy instead of python for-loops. In your case the numpy code would look somewhat like:

```
def asc_process_single_numpy(asc_array):
    nodata_value = np.nan
    raster_size_y = 1
    skip = 2
    xllcornor = 0
    yllcornor = 0
    cellsize  = 1
    rows = np.arange(0,asc_array.shape[0],skip)[:,np.newaxis]
    cols = np.arange(0,asc_array.shape[1],skip)

    #for row in rows for col in cols
    x = np.zeros((len(rows),len(cols))) + xllcornor + (cols * cellsize)
    y = np.zeros((len(rows),len(cols))) + yllcornor + raster_size_y - (rows * cellsize)
    z = asc_array[::skip,::skip]
    return np.asarray([x,y,z]).T.transpose((1,0,2)).reshape( (int(len(rows)*len(cols)), 3) )

A = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
%timeit asc_process_single(A)
%timeit asc_process_single_listcomprehension(A)
%timeit asc_process_single_numpy(A)
```

```
183 ms ± 13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
210 ms ± 2.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
11.3 ms ± 222 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: What is the [:, np.newaxis] for?

Comment: thats strange. at which position do you get an error? the addition of `[:,no.newaxis]` tells numpy to handle the sum at `y=...` differently. Here an array `rows` is added row-wise to the matrix `np.zeros(...)`. Without the `[:,no.newaxis]` it would be column-wise.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can imagine that's slowing you down is that in the original code, you put `asc_array[row, col]` into a temporary variable, while in the list comprehension, you evaluate it twice.

There are two things you might want to try:

1. Assign the value to `val_z` in the "if" statement using a walrus operator, or
2. Add `for val_z in [asc_array[row, col]]` after the other two `for`s.

Good luck.